# Configurable product - How to update MGS_Lookbook block on simple product on swatch selection?

Tags: configurable-product, pdp

Configurable product swatch selection - how can we update the simple product MGS_Lookbook block on configurable product page swatch selection?

Comment: The module you're talking about is from a third-party vendor - not from Magento core. Without example code or what inside the block or how the block runs, we cannot help you come up with a solution. Please include some example code around the target block.